# Vector<pair>: emplace without constructing pair-inner objects

Tags: c++, vector, std-pair, emplace

Suppose we have two `struct`s:

```
struct FIRST{
    int a=0;
    int b=0;
    FIRST(int a, int b): a(a), b(b){}
};
struct SECOND{
    int c=0;
    int d=0;
    SECOND(int c, int d): c(c), d(d){}
};
```

And we have a `vector` of `pair`s of them:

```
std::vector<std::pair<FIRST, SECOND>> abcd;
```

What I want is to `emplace` a `pair` without constructing both elements, so this is not what I want:

```
abcd.emplace_back(FIRST(1,2),SECOND(3,4));
```

But this is not going to work

```
abcd.emplace_back(1,2,3,4);
```

How? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std::piecewise_construct`:

```
abcd.emplace_back(
    std::piecewise_construct,
    std::forward_as_tuple(1, 2),
    std::forward_as_tuple(3, 4)
);
```